# autocomplete does not work within git hook, tty problem?

Tags: python, git, autocomplete, githooks

I am implementing autocomplete feature in one of the git hooks (prepare-commit-msg) in python. It works when I call it as a normal python script, i.e., `python auto_complete_hook.py`. However, it does not work (pressing TAB does not show options) when its called within the git hook environment. In the git hook I have a tty attached, i.e., `sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')` before calling `input()` function.

What am I missing? I would appreciate any pointers on how to solve this.

Git hook code:

```
sys.stdin = open('/dev/tty', 'r')
autocompleter = MyCompleter(keywords_list)
readline.set_completer(autocompleter.complete)
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
input()
```

`autocompleter.complete` function returns a list of possible matches.